# Using Jquery load to bring content in from 2 HTML pages

Tags: jquery, html, load

I am trying to load some content from multiple pages into one page. I know that these fire in order, so only pageB2's content will load since it's last. Is there a way to have both pageB and pageB2's content appear in the new page when the user clicks on #nav_b?

```
$(function(){
            $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
                $("#main_text").load("pageB.html h2,h3,span,#hidden");  
            });
            $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
                $("#main_text").load("pageB2.html h2,h3,span,#hidden");  
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacky but working solution:

```
        $(function() {
            $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
                var pageB = '', pageB2 = '';
                var $mainText = $("#main_text");
                $mainText.load("pageB.html h2,h3,span,#hidden", function() {
                    pageB = $mainText.html();
                    $mainText.html(pageB + pageB2);
                });
                $mainText.load("pageB2.html h2,h3,span,#hidden", function() {
                    pageB2 = $mainText.html();
                    $mainText.html(pageB + pageB2);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is nice. Hacky is good, since I'm just starting. I have about 30 more pages (pageB3, pageB4, etc.) so I can play with this and see what I can do.

Comment: this is not correct answer as it will overwrite the HTML loaded by first call when the pageB2 is loaded. Remember! its AJAX (Asynchronous)

Comment: @Patel yes, but note that it saves the contents of the HTML after loading into the pageB variable. The contents will appear in order regardless of the timing of the pages' return.

Comment: ohh yes... i missed it :)

Answer (score 0):

`load` overwrites the content when the second call returns. Couldn't you use e.g. [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)?

Example (untested). Here the data are appended to the target element.

```
$(function(){
    $("#nav_b").on("click", function(){
        $.get( "pageB.html h2,h3,span,#hidden", function( data ) {
              $("#main_text").append( data );
        });
        $.get( "pageB2.html h2,h3,span,#hidden", function( data ) {
              $("#main_text").append( data );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm new to coding and I learned jQuery load yesterday. I'll look into .get(). I appreciate the help.